# Utilizar elvis operator em conjunto com ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

Olá, tenho o seguinte elemento:

Produto.descricao_b2w.**descricao**

As vezes, esse **descricao** não existe nesse produto, então quando o eu tento aplicar o ngModel e *ngIf nele eu recebo:

> Cannot read property 'descricao' of null

Esse é meu template:

```
<textarea *ngIf="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao !== null" rows="4" [(ngModel)]="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao" readonly type="text" name="descricaob2w" id="descricaob2w{{i}}" class="form-control">
```

Tentei o elvis de algumas formas diferentes, mas nenhuma conseguiu atingir meu objetivo, o ngModel não consegue encontrar a descrição porque ela realmente não existe no objeto, só existe as vezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objeto anterior pode estar nulo, tente desta maneira.

```
<textarea *ngIf="produto.descricao_b2w !== null" rows="4" [(ngModel)]="produto.descricao_b2w.descricao" readonly type="text" name="descricaob2w" id="descricaob2w{{i}}" class="form-control">
```